# Find the interval of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^n(x-3)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

My Attempt

Using the ratio test $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

$$L=|x-3|.\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n.(n+1)}{n^n}=
\\= |x-3|.\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)}{n}\right)^n.\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1) =|x-3|.\infty $$

So $L<1$ to converge

$$|x-3|.\infty <1 \\
x=3$$

How can i prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n.lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)=\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes except that your two "$<1$" should be "$\le1$" (*necessary* condition for convergence). But a direct proof (of trivial divergence if $x\ne3$) would be more elegant imo.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, but how can i awnser the $lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$

Comment: I thought you knew it was a positive number and made it implicit when writing $=|x-3|\infty$. Actually, this number is $e.$ Anyway, a direct proof  (of trivial divergence if $x≠3$)  won't need that: just notice what happens for all $n\ge\frac1{|x-3|}$.

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac1n$ and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e.$

Comment: So it will be $e.\infty = \infty$

Comment: Well, not previously said **why.** @AnneBauval